# Numpy variable slice indices

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

```
dataset[batch_idx:, :, :, :]
```

This collects batches of 3-dimensional data.

```
dataset[batch_idx:, :]
```

This collects batches of 1-dimensional data.

How do we collect batches of n-dimensional data?

Looking for a solution that works for numpy and h5py

Comment: You can replace the ':' with one '...'.  Or just omit them, `numpy` adds trailing ':' automatically.

Comment: `h5py` indexing generally tries to match `numpy`: http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#reading-writing-data

Comment: @hpaulj self.history[i, :, :] = self.pre_proc(obs)

Comment: self.history[i] and self.history[i, ...] neither works...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about h5py, but for numpy I always use `slice`.

```
slices = tuple([batch_idx] + [slice(None)]*(dim))
dataset[slices]
```

Each `slice(None)` is equivalent to one of the semicolons, so you just need to make a list of them that fits the number of dimensions you have. So if dim is 1 the above code will collect slices of one dimensional data, if dim is 3 it will collect slices of three dimensional data, etc. If you want to do more complicated slicing, you can, as an example, use `slice(3,10,2)` to replace `3:10:2`,  in an n-dimensional slice. Hope that helps!